# Averiguar el valor máximo de un array recursivamente en Java

Tags: java, array, recursión

He encontrado este código que te devuelve el máximo de un array de forma recursiva, pero no sé en qué momento hace las comparaciones para quedarse con el máximo de la izquierda y el máximo por la derecha , ¿me podríais ayudar a entenderlo?

```
public static int Max(int[] array, int i, int j) {
    int med, max_left, max_right;
    if (i == j)
        return array[i];
    else
        med = (i + j) / 2;
    max_left = Max(array, i, med);
    max_right = Max(array, med + 1, j);
    if (max_left > max_right)
        return max_left;
    else
        return max_right;
}
```

Comment: Aquí se queda con el  màximo de la izquierda: `max_left = Max (array, i, med);`, y aquí con el de la derecha: `max_right = Max (array, med+1,j );` Aquí: `if (max_left > max_right)
     return max_left;
     else
     return max_right;` dice esto: *Si el máximo de la izquierda es mayor al máximo de la derecha, aquel es mayor, entonces devuélvelo (el máximo de la izquierda); de lo contrario, es mayor el máximo de la derecha, entonces devuélvelo.* Me parece que esto se puede hacer mucho más simple con expresiones Lambda, a partir de Java 8.

Comment: Si pero esto es ya cuando ha almacenado los valores max_left y max_right , ¿pero en qué momento max_left es el valor máximo del subarray de la izquierda y lo mismo con max_right del subarray de la derecha?

Comment: Es que lo que no entiendo al completo es cómo funciona la recursion en este metodo

Comment: Edité el comentario, lo he indicado al principio del mismo.

Comment: vale ya lo he entendido gracias, el problema era que no estaba comprendiendo como funcionaba la recursion

Comment: te explico, cada vez de la función recurre a sí misma (en el caso de máx left), lo que correspondería a `j` en los parámetros de la función se va reduciendo, y siempre devuelve el mayor valor de la comparación que hace, asegurandose así que el valor máximo de la mitad izquierda acabará en el hilo principal de la función en `max_left`, pues lo mismo ocurre con `max_right`, la funcion va recorriendose y reduciendo los valores posibles desde la mitad en adelante. Cuando han llegado al final de las comparaciones , `i` será siempre igual a `j`, con lo que devolverá ese número. `i` y `j` son los del

Comment: Gracias me has resuelto mi duda, y es que yo pensaba que esa comparacion solo se realizaba al terminar el metodo, porque pensaba que el return ya te hacía salir del metodo.

Comment: En este caso, no sale del metodo con el return porque digamos que hay como más llamadas recursivas pendientes y hasta que no acaben no termina no?

Comment: Cuando realizas recursividad, antes de seguir con la función principal resuelve las funciones que implementes dentro de la principal, y así sucede en casacada cuando hay recursividad, cuando ya se resuelve la más específica empieza a resolver las demás de forma jerárquica desde la recursividad más profunda hasta la función principal, una vez termina todas las recursividades, continúa con el código principal y llega por fín a la clausua `return`

Comment: PD: hay que tener mucho cuidado a la hora de utilizar recursividad, ya que puedes cargar a la memoria de la maquina virtual java por consecuencia de realizar llamadas infinitas (`infinito` no es un concepto que manejen demasiado bien las máquinas xD) por ejemplo `public void habla (){System.out.println("hola"); habla();}` petaría, ya que estás llamando a `hola` dentro de sí misma, sin darle una forma de dejar de hacerlo, con lo cual estarías intentando llegar al fondo de la recursividad, pero nunca llegarías, como consecuencia nunca resolvería ninguna de las llamadas a `hola()`

Comment: Entiendo, por eso imagino que se necesita siempre un caso base... Gracias Enrique me has sido de gran ayuda

Comment: De nada, me alegro de haber ayudado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descompondremos tu problema al entenderlo en problemas más pequeños imaginando una ejecución completa, ejecutamos max sobre un array de 8 elementos:

```
int[]arr = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
//Aquí entramos en la ejecución principal
int max = Max(arr,0,arr.lenght.1);
```

primera ejecución i es 0, j es 7 (primera y última posición del array), se mete en la cláusula else, calcula el punto medio (3) y ejecuta de nuevo dos instancias del código:

```
//Ejecución principal:
max_left  = Max(arr,0,3); //Es decir {0,1,2,3}
max_right = Max(arr,4,7); //Es decir {4,5,6,7}
```

Es importante que veas que aquí la ejecución salta de nuevo a la cabecera de la función, porque hay que calcular `max_left` para el caso más general, por tanto la segunda ejecución tendrá que esperar, Nos metemos en la primera "sub ejecución", es decir `Max(arr,0,3)`. Aquí i y j siguen sin ser iguales, así que volverá a dividir la ejecución en 2, las partes del array {0,1} y {1,2} y volverá a subdividirse igual que en la anterior, es decir

```
//Sub ejecución 1
max_left  = Max(arr,0,1); 
max_right = Max(arr,2,3);
```

Volvemos a seguir con "max_left", porque aún no se ha llenado esa variable, es fácil ver que la siguiente ejecución será

```
//Sub ejecución 2
max_left  = Max(arr,0,0); //i=j=0
max_right = Max(arr,1,1); //i=j=1
```

Continuamos con max_left, recibimos i = 0 y j= 0, así que aquí sí nos metemos en el if, devolviendo arr[0] (valor 0 porque es la primera posición).

```
//Sub ejecución 3
return arr[0];
```

En este momento hemos alcanzado un caso base así que en la Sub ejecución 2 estamos de enhorabuena, en este momento max left es igual a 0

```
max_left = ... //Ejecutado y con valor 0
max_right = Max(arr,1,1); //Por ejecutar, devolverá el valor 1
```

La ejecución de Max_right devolverá 2 de la misma forma que la sub ejecución 3 (estamos al mismo nivel). Piensa que en el mismo nivel tendremos 8 sub ejecuciones (no se ejecutan a la vez) `Max(arr,0,0); Max(arr,1,1) ... Max(arr,7,7)`

```
             Ejecución general (0,7)
  Max_left  /            Max_right \
       Nivel 1(0,3)            Nivel 1(4,7)
   L  /        R \              /         \
    (0,1)       (2,3)        (4,5)      (6,7)
  L / R\         /  \         /  \        /  \
(0,0) (1,1)   (2,2) (3,3)  (4,4) (5,5) (6,6) (7,7)
```

Llegados a este punto nos encontramos en 0,1 con las variables Right y Left llenas, por lo que subimos un nivel en el árbol que he pintado arriba. Ese nivel está listo para comparar

```
if (max_left > max_right)
    return max_left;
else
    return max_right;
```

Así devolverá el  máximo entre 0 y 1, que en este caso será 1 y estará almacenado en right. Al llegar a una sentencia `return` subiremos un nivel en el árbol, en este caso al (0,3), quien ya tendrá llena la variable left y tendrá que llenar la right, por lo que bajará al nivel (2,3), de ahí llenará sus variables con (2) y (3) y devolverá el valor más alto (3), llenando la variable Right de (0,3) y permitiendo llenar la left de (0,7) y bajar a la rama (4,7). Así sucesivamente se compararán al final en el nivel (0,7) los niveles 3 y 7 y se devolverá el valor más alto, 7 en este caso.

Comment: Aunque ya entendí el código en su día, le agradezco mucho que se haya tomado la molestia de explicarlo de esta forma tan visual y detallada, un saludo